# How do I set the background colour of NSTabView?

Tags: objective-c, tabview

```
[tabView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.227f green:0.251f blue:0.337 alpha:0.8];
```

The above code does not work :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTabView doesn't have a `setBackgroundColor` method, so I think you cann't use it as is. One of the approaches to solve it is subclassing NSTabView and override `drawRect` method. Check this version of custom tab control on github - https://github.com/ciaran/psmtabbarcontrol